# Primordial gravitational waves evolution equation

Tags: gravitational-waves, cosmological-inflation

I'm reading the review by Domenech ["Scalar induced gravitational waves review"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.01398.pdf) and he says that equation 3.15
$$\ddot{h}_{ij}+3H\dot{h}_{ij}-a^{-2}\Delta h_{ij}=S$$
where I use $S$ as an abbreviation, coincides with the following equation
$$h''_{ij}+2\mathcal{H}h'_{ij}-\nabla^2h_{ij}=\tilde{S}$$where again $\tilde{S}$ is just an abbreviation. My question now is why the factor 3 in the first equation becomes a factor 2 in the second one? I know that $\mathcal{H}=H/a$ but still I can't understand why the two equations should coincide.

Answer (score 2):

Overdots are derivatives with respect to time $t$, while primes are derivatives with respect to conformal time $\tau$, where $\mathrm{d}\tau=\mathrm{d}t/a$. But
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}\tau^2}
=
a\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}a\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
=
a\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}+a\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}
\right]
=
a^2\left[H\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\right],
$$
so the $h''_{ij}$ term contains the third $H\dot{h}_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks!! It was exactly what I was doing, but I was using the relation in the article: $\mathcal{H}=H/a$ which is wrong! I didnt check that relation and obvoiusly the calculations weren't correct. The correct relation is $\mathcal{H}=aH$, isn't it?

Comment: @StefanoManzoni Yeah $\mathcal{H}=aH$ sounds more familiar, since it makes $\mathcal{H}^{-1}$ the comoving Hubble length.

Comment: thanks a lot, now it makes sense!